# GSON Parse Json date with single set of quotes

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm reading trying to find the simplest way to parse a date returned from a rails API, but the date is returned like:

```
"start_time": "2015-01-28T10:30:00.000+00:00",
"end_time": "2015-01-28T11:30:00.000+00:00",
```

The single set of quotes seem to be the problem.
So basically is there a simple way to tell the dateformat to ignore this or should I write a custom deserializer for date objects? My current Gson object is defined as:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .registerTypeAdapter(Long.class, new LongTypeAdapter())
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
            .create();
```

Which is good, but can't handle the date in it's current format, it returns JsonSyntaxException, if it was like this:

```
"\"2015-01-28T10:30:00.000+00:00\""
```

It would work fine.

I can't seem to find anything in the Gson docs that offers a simple way to handle dates like this, and all the other questions on here seem to say to change the input, but since it's coming from an API I don't have that luxury.

This is being done using Android and Retrofit if that makes any difference.

Comment: Can you just remove the single quotes in the format string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to implement your own adapter for the date, it seems to be the easiest way.

There are some examples here : https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-type-adapters-for-common-classes-1

Comment: Yeah that's what I've done, I just thought I may be missing something simple as it seems like it must be a common thing.